# what is the probability of getting at least $1$ Y-faced coin?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 44 X-faced coins and $6$ Y-faced coins. (The coins are identical in size.) If $5$ coins (X- or Y-faced) are randomly picked from the bag, what is the probability of getting at least $1$ Y-faced coin?

My approach would be to simply do 1 - P(all X-faced coins) and we know

$$ P(all \; X-faced) = \frac{ {44 \choose 5 } }{ {50 \choose 5} } $$

And so the answer is

$$ 1 - \frac{ {44 \choose 5 } }{ {50 \choose 5} } $$

IS this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The other way (harder) would have been to add the number of ways you get 1 $Y$-faced coin, 2 $Y$-faced coins, etc. and divide it bye $50 \choose 5$:
$$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^5 {6 \choose n}{44 \choose 5-n}}{{50 \choose 5}} \approx 0.4874$$